# Unity3D free in game purchase solution

Tags: unity, microtransactions

Am making an android game with unity and i want to add an in-game purchase feature, i looked around and all the suggestion lead to non-free plugins (mainly prime31 plugin) but in the current moment i cannot afford to invest in some of these plugins, does anyone of you have a free solution for this "problem" ?

thank you

Comment: Make it yourself ;)

Comment: honestly i think that this would be the best solution but i never build a plugin before, how hard it is to make one ? and do you have any suggestion to start with ? thank you

Answer (score 3):

You could try these plugins, they are both free.

http://project.soom.la/

https://github.com/onepf/OpenIAB/tree/master/unity_plugin